# can't get json data with api

Tags: javascript, json

I am using below javascript and html to get the json data. But i can't make it work with this api.It just return blank result. I have checked the api link is working so i don't think is the server problem. Please help!

html

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="balance"></div>
```

javascript

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"https://xmg.minerclaim.net/index.php?page=api&action=public",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(typeof data); // -- Object
      var json = data;

      $('#balance').html(json.hashrate);

    }
  });
});
```

json data

```
{"pool_name":"minerclaim.net","hashrate":60185.64096,"workers":1056,"shares_this_round":168700,"last_block":1531882,"network_hashrate":61752985,"fee":1,"payout":"prop"}
```

Comment: Is there any error in the Javascript console? You're probably running into CORS problems.

Comment: The problem is that the server does not support CORS, so the only way you will be able to get this JSON is if you execute this script within the same domain

Comment: As both above already wrote about CORS, you could try one other way of returning the JSON without this problems, by using PHP cURL. So, write a simple .php-file, put a cURL command in there pointing towards the URL you're requesting and add the URL of your .php-file to your `$.ajax`.

Comment: @FrankW. I had wrote a simple .php file, and the php indeed can display the json data. But my ajax still can get the json data . I have already point the phpfile to my url. I had notice that the php file will add bool(true) at the end of json data. Will this be a problem? Here is my php code `$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xmg.minerclaim.net/index.php?page=api&action=public');
curl_setopt($curl，CURLOPT_HEADER，1); 
$data = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($data);`

Comment: It adds bool(true) to your PHP file, because you are using `var_dump($data)` where `$data` in your example is the output of `curl_exec`. I'll write you an example as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned above, you are getting `bool(true)` in your PHP output, because the usage of [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

An example of a PHP file you could use:

```
    <?php

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xmg.minerclaim.net/index.php?page=api&action=public");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Some error:' . curl_error($ch);
            die();
        }

        // You want your browser to think it's JSON, as we return as JSON
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo($result);

        curl_close($ch);
?>
```

You can copy + paste this into a new PHP file, point the `$.ajax`-url to that new file and see the magic happen. The example above works for me as I'm getting results back.

As for your javascript, you could also try to add `contentType: "application/json",` after `dataType: "json",", as this will make sure the content-type of the headers that are returned are set.